# jQuery Model popup do not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Im new at jQuery and try to get this to work. Can someone tell me whats wrong.
When I click on the link in demo.html, a "FadeIn"-div should popup.
But nothing happens when the link is clicked?

**File: jquery.reveal.js**

```
    (function($) {

/*---------------------------
 Defaults for Reveal
----------------------------*/

/*---------------------------
 Listener for data-reveal-id attributes
----------------------------*/

    $('a[data-reveal-id]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var modalLocation = $(this).prop('data-reveal-id');
        $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
    });

/*---------------------------
 Extend and Execute
----------------------------*/

    $.fn.reveal = function(options) {


        var defaults = {  
            animation: 'fadeAndPop', //fade, fadeAndPop, none
            animationspeed: 300, //how fast animtions are
            closeonbackgroundclick: true, //if you click background will modal close?
            dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal' //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
        }; 

        //Extend dem' options
        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options); 

        return this.each(function() {

/*---------------------------
 Global Variables
----------------------------*/
            var modal = $(this),
                topMeasure  = parseInt(modal.css('top')),
                topOffset = modal.height() + topMeasure,
                locked = false,
                modalBG = $('.reveal-modal-bg');

/*---------------------------
 Create Modal BG
----------------------------*/
            if(modalBG.length == 0) {
                modalBG = $('<div class="reveal-modal-bg" />').insertAfter(modal);
            }           

/*---------------------------
 Open & Close Animations
----------------------------*/
            //Entrance Animations
            modal.bind('reveal:open', function () {
              modalBG.unbind('click.modalEvent');
                $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).unbind('click.modalEvent');
                if(!locked) {
                    lockModal();
                    if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                        modal.css({'top': $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset, 'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible'});
                        modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                        modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                            "top": $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure + 'px',
                            "opacity" : 1
                        }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                    }
                    if(options.animation == "fade") {
                        modal.css({'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible', 'top': $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                        modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                        modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                            "opacity" : 1
                        }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                    } 
                    if(options.animation == "none") {
                        modal.css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'top':$(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                        modalBG.css({"display":"block"});   
                        unlockModal()               
                    }
                }
                modal.unbind('reveal:open');
            });     

            //Closing Animation
            modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {
              if(!locked) {
                    lockModal();
                    if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                        modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                        modal.animate({
                            "top":  $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset + 'px',
                            "opacity" : 0
                        }, options.animationspeed/2, function() {
                            modal.css({'top':topMeasure, 'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden'});
                            unlockModal();
                        });                 
                    }   
                    if(options.animation == "fade") {
                        modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                        modal.animate({
                            "opacity" : 0
                        }, options.animationspeed, function() {
                            modal.css({'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                            unlockModal();
                        });                 
                    }   
                    if(options.animation == "none") {
                        modal.css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                        modalBG.css({'display' : 'none'});  
                    }       
                }
                modal.unbind('reveal:close');
            });     

/*---------------------------
 Open and add Closing Listeners
----------------------------*/
            //Open Modal Immediately
        modal.trigger('reveal:open')

            //Close Modal Listeners
            var closeButton = $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
              modal.trigger('reveal:close')
            });

            if(options.closeonbackgroundclick) {
                modalBG.css({"cursor":"pointer"})
                modalBG.bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
                  modal.trigger('reveal:close')
                });
            }
            $('body').keyup(function(e) {
                if(e.which===27){ modal.trigger('reveal:close'); } // 27 is the keycode for the Escape key
            });


/*---------------------------
 Animations Locks
----------------------------*/
            function unlockModal() { 
                locked = false;
            }
            function lockModal() {
                locked = true;
            }   

        });//each call
    }//orbit plugin call
})(jQuery);
```

File: demo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Reveal Demo</title>

    <!-- Attach our CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reveal.css">   

    <!-- Attach necessary scripts -->
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.reveal.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        body { font-family: "HelveticaNeue","Helvetica-Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; }
        .big-link { display:block; margin-top: 100px; text-align: center; font-size: 70px; color: #06f; }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal">
        Fade and Pop
    </a>    

    <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-animation="fade">
        Fade
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-animation="none">
        None
    </a>

    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
        <h1>Reveal Modal Goodness</h1>
        <p>This is a default modal in all its glory, but any of the styles here can easily be changed in the CSS.</p>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>

</body>
```

Thanks.. Hope someone can tell me what the problem is.

Comment: you just said nothing happened, and we don't know what should actually happen. So it'll be helpful if you be more specific with your problem in code.

Comment: When I click on the link, a FadeIn div should popup. :) But nothing happen

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors? Use some kind of debugging tool to check if something is wrong with something in your script

Comment: Undefined is not a function (evaluating  $('a[data-reveal-id]').on') But I am not sure what i should change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change prop to attr in line

```
  var modalLocation = $(this).prop('data-reveal-id');// change this line to

  var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
```

and add reveal.css file it will work

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YfSQn/

Comment: How can I change the div content to iframe, where the link button tells which site it should popup

Comment: @user2923444 You can use fancybox . It has a lot of features and very easy to use. you can use iframe with ease